# Как правильно использовать AlarmManager и Service?

Tags: android, service, android-alarm-manager

Всем доброго времени суток. В свое приложение хочу добавить уведомления. Создал Service в котором в **onStartCommand()** выполняется загрузка данных с сервера, далее данные с сервера сравниваются с данными приложения и если данные различаются, то приходит уведомление о обновлении данных.

Проблема заключается в том, что проверку данных мне нужно сделать каждый час. Но с помощью **Alarm Manager** этого сделать не получается. Уведомления приходят, только если поставить интервал в 5 секунд. Мой код **onStartCommand():**

```js
@Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        
        Calendar time = Calendar.getInstance();
        time.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
        time.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 60);
        PendingIntent servicePendingIntent = 
        PendingIntent.getService(this,SERVICE_REQUEST_CODE, 
        intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, 
        System.currentTimeMillis(),servicePendingIntent);
    am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,System.currentTimeMillis(),AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY,servicePendingIntent);

        // Загрузка Data.zip и после распаковка
        new DownloadDataZip().execute("ССЫЛКА",
                "Data.zip");

        return Service.START_STICKY;
    }
```

Запускаю сервис таким образом:

```js
startService(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyService.class));
```

Подскажите пожалуйста как правильно осуществить мою задачу. В кратце нужно, чтобы сервис запускался каждый час.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это плохой подход решения задачи. Вообще не желательно делать так, чтобы сервис запрашивал данные с сайта и делал сравнение с данными на телефоне. Лучше чтобы с сервера приходил пуш, о том что данные изменились и уже после делать сравнение данных.

Но если рассматривать только этот вариант, то вам необходимо посмотреть в сторону `WorkManager`. `Service` и `AlarmManager` вам не помогут, т.к. с 6 андроида появился `Doze Mode`, который ограничивает работу в бэкграунде.

Comment: Действительно WorkManager самый лучший вариант